# Propriedade ICollection na classe não é instanciada

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho a classe produto e nessa classe tenho essa propriedade

```
public virtual ICollection<CspProduct> CspItems { get; set; }
```

Aqui pegos os produtos

```
var products = _productService.GetAll().ToList();
```

e aqui os itens

```
var items = _orderService.GetItemsFromOrder(_order).Where(x => x.CurrencyCode == 23).ToList();
```

Fiz o Join abaixo

```
var result = products.Join(
                items,
                p => p.Id,
                i => i.ProductId,
                (p, i) => new { produtos = p, itens = i }) 
                .Where(x => x.produtos.Hidden == false && x.itens.CurrencyCode == 23)
                .Select(x => new SubscriptionProductModel
                {
                    Name = x.produtos.Name,
                    Partnumber = x.produtos.PartNumber,
                    Markup = 0M,
                    OfferUri = x.produtos.CspItems.Select(s => new { s.OfferUri}).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                    Dollar = x.itens.BasePriceUSD,
                    Real = x.itens.BasePriceBRL
                }).ToList();
```

Acontece que quando eu chego nessa linha dentro do Join

```
OfferUri = x.produtos.CspItems.Select(s => new { s.OfferUri}).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
```

Dá erro de:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Como eu faço para instanciar um objeto dentro de outro quando estou executando uma lambda?

Comment: Removendo o FirstOrDefault() não pego mais o erro, mas não consigo trazer o valor do campo, apenas isso: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[CSP.SubscriptionCenter.Core.Domain.MicrosoftEntities.CspProduct,<>f__AnonymousType32`1[System.String]]`

Comment: o products ta vindo de uma consulta no banco? talvez seja questão de por um include pra ele trazer seu relacionamento, no seu caso específico ai não adiantaria instanciar, afinal ia ter objeto mas não ia ter valores

Comment: Sim, products vem de um IQueryable direto. Esse Include está correto? `var products = _productService.GetAll().Include(x => x.CspItems).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser que a função FirstOrDefault esteja retornando null pois a lista CspItems esteja vazia, ou que a váriavel s da expressão lambda esteja nula. Se você quer que a variável OfferUri seja preenchida mesmo com essas condições utilize o seguinte código:

```
OfferUri = x.produtos.CspItems.Select(s => new { s?.OfferUri }).FirstOrDefault()?.ToString()
```

Porém acho que se sua intenção é pegar o valor em s.OfferUri deveria ser asssim:

```
OfferUri = x.produtos.CspItems.FirstOrDefault(s => s?.OfferUri )
```

Comment: Weiner Lemes, Um Uri apenas vem nulo, por isso o erro como comentou. Parabens! Funcionou, mas peguei isso: `{ OfferUri = 031c9e47-4802-4248-838e-778fb1d2cc05 }` e eu preciso apenas disso: `031c9e47-4802-4248-838e-778fb1d2cc05`. Como elimino as chaves e o OfferUri? Funcionou nessa abordagem: `OfferUri = x.produtos.CspItems.Select(s => new { s?.OfferUri }).FirstOrDefault()?.ToString()` a outra está dando erro

Comment: Resolvi colocando um OfferUri após o FirstOrDefault() e ficou dessa forma: `OfferUri = x.produtos.CspItems.Select(s => new { s?.OfferUri }).FirstOrDefault()?.OfferUri.ToString()`, mas vou considerar a resposta do Weiner Lemes

Comment: Fiz ainda melhor. Fiz assim e funcionou: `OfferUri = x.produtos.CspItems.FirstOrDefault()?.OfferUri.ToString()`